# Mass Transit and .NetFramework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rabbitmq, nuget-package, masstransit

I want to add MassTransit 7.2.2 to my desktop application targetting .NET Framework v4.7.2 (Nuget package) - but I get this error message :

> Impossible d’installer le package « MassTransit 7.2.2 ». Vous essayez d’installer ce package dans un projet ciblant « .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 », mais le package ne contient aucun fichier de contenu ou référence d’assembly compatible avec cette infrastructure. Pour plus d’informations, contactez le créateur du package"

Using Google Translate:

> Unable to install "Mass Transit 7.2.2" package. You try to install this package in a project targeting ".NETFramework, Version = v4.7.2", but the package does not contain any content files or assembly references compatible with this framework. For more information, contact the creator of the package "

How to resolve this please?

Comment: Which package? MassTransit itself uses .NET Standard 2.0, which should be compatible with .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: MassTransit....  Yes it should be compatible .. why I have this error message when I try to import  with nuget package ...?

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should change target .net framework of your project to 4.8
i was that problem too .i added masstransit 8.0.2 in my desktop project in .net framework 4.8

try it agin
good lock

Comment: I added MassTransit 7.2.3 to my project.....